# Proper response to edit warring

Tags: discussion, editing

What should the appropriate response be to edit warring on questions?  There's a question I've written an answer to so I've notices that various contributors keep undoing each other's edits.

The question I am referring to: [How Big were the Siberian Traps ORIGINALLY?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16335/how-big-were-the-siberian-traps-originally)

Comment: Same as everything else that can't be done by the community. Flag for a moderator, who can lock it and sort out the issue. I've now flagged that particular question to point out the issues and request appropriate actions.

Comment: @Nij Thank you.  I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: The moderator hichris solved it by editing and locking the post. The asker was a bit pigheaded, but if you search in main meta tittles shouldn't be capitalized.